# How to test unmanaged extension for Neo4j server using JUnit

Tags: java, http, junit, neo4j

I'm trying to develop some test file for a Neo4j project. I have found that Neo4j provides JUnit Rule (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions-testing.html) and I have try to use it for testing. However, it does not work as intendant.

My code is exactly as in the Neo4j help page:

```
@Rule
public Neo4jRule neo4j = new Neo4jRule()
    .withFixture( "CREATE (admin:Admin)" )
    .withFixture( new Function<GraphDatabaseService, Void>()
    {
        @Override
        public Void apply( GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService ) throws RuntimeException
        {
            try (Transaction tx = graphDatabaseService.beginTx())
            {
                graphDatabaseService.createNode( DynamicLabel.label( "Admin" ));
                tx.success();
            }
            return null;
        }
    } );

@Test
public void shouldWorkWithServer() throws Exception
{
     // Given
    URI serverURI = neo4j.httpURI();

    // When I access the server
    HTTP.Response response = HTTP.GET( serverURI.toString() );

    // Then it should reply
    assertEquals(200, response.status());
}
```

I'm receiving this error:

```
Failed tests:   shouldWorkWithServer(test.Test): expected:<200> but was:<500>
```

I have try to resolve 'db/data/' path:

```
URI serverURI = neo4j.httpURI().resolve("db/data/");
```

The result has been same. I have also try to use TestServerBuilders instead and generate Http Authentication header with default 'neo4j:neo4j' and have got same error again. The server does created, I can access to it via getGraphDatabaseService() and see the nodes, but I can not access it via HTTP.

The Neo4j version is 3.2.1 and the JUnit version is 4.11

Comment: Since you're getting a 500, there should be somewhere a stacktrace. My gut feeling says you're lacking the `neo4j-io` jar with classifier tests, http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-io/.

Comment: I have actually found the problem. javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0 artefact recommended by Neo4j manual actually conflicting with org.neo4j.test:neo4j-harness:2.3.1. I have removed rs library and now everything magically work.

Comment: @Dmitry thanks for the heads up on this!!

Comment: Thanks for this! you can also declare the jaxRS dependency as the last one when using maven. It will have the same effect

Comment: @Rwanou Please add your comment as answer for future reference

Answer (score 0):

If using Maven, do not forget that the order you declare the dependencies has an importance. Therefore, you should declare the "provided" dependencies after the "test" ones, so the implementation of the test library is used prior to the provided one. That is good practice for all the JEE related libraries.

In your case, make sure you declare *javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0* after *org.neo4j.test:neo4j-harness:2.3.1*